# Detect Textview Scrolling and Tableview Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TextView and a Tableview in UIView. Im trying to detect  either scrolling is textview scrolling or tableview scrolling?There is any code for this? Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate, so all you need to implement these methods -**scrollViewWillBeginDragging and -scrollViewDidScroll**

```
   - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (scrollView == myTableView){
   // Your logic here.....
    }
    if (scrollView == textView)
    {  // Your logic here..
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**`UITextView` & `UITableView` both are implemented by using `UIScrollView`**

You can identify the which control scrolling & direction by implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if ([scrollview isKindeOfClass: [UITextView Class]]) {
       //UITextView
    } else if ([scrollview isKindeOfClass: [UITableView Class]]) {
      // UITableView
    }

    // Identifying direction 
    CGPoint point = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];
    if (point.y > 0) {
        // Dragging down
    } else {
        // Dragging up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` delegate and check. Set `UITextViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDelegate` and check in method

**Example**:

#### Objective-C

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if scrollView == tableView {

      }
     if scrollView == textView {

      }
    }
```

#### Swift 3.0

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == tableView {

        }
        if scrollView == textView {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `UIScrollView` already embedded in `UITableView` and `UITextView`
[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll?language=objc)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UITableView & UITextView are a subclass of UIScrollview.** So all the **UIScrollView** you will get when you scroll **UITableView**. Here you get a list of [UIScrollView method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate).

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` and `UITableView` are both **subclasses** of `UIScrollView` , so both of them triggers the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

assume that `__scrollView` and `__textView` are your respective `UIScrollView` and `UITextView`,

Overriding `UIScrollViewDelegate` method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      if ( scrollView ==  __scrollView ) {
            // UIScrollView is scrolled
      }else if ( scrollView ==  __textView ){
            // UITextView is scrolled
      }
}
```